# How to synchronize several toggle buttons in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to have a toggle button on each tab of my form. This toggle button is then used later in the code to create a script based on whether the value is true or false from the toggle button. I would like that when I check one toggle button on the first tab, then all the other toggle buttons on the other tabs with the same name show the same on/off position. Is this possible?

Comment: Binding to the same property with notification will achieve this. Hard to add anything else without seeing more details.

Comment: You can bind their state to one property of your ViewModel, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a look to the MVVM pattern.

You need a ViewModel that will store the (common) state of the toggle buttons.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool? _isToggleButtonChecked;

    public bool? IsToggleButtonChecked
    {
        get => _isToggleButtonChecked;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_isToggleButtonChecked, value))
                return;

            _isToggleButtonChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, you need to bind the toggle button `IsChecked` property to the view model `IsToggleButtonChecked`:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </TabControl.DataContext>

    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <ToggleButton Content="Click me"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleButtonChecked}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <ToggleButton Content="Click me"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleButtonChecked}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Tab 3">
        <ToggleButton Content="Click me"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleButtonChecked}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```